# How to create a nested dictonary in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Team, I need your help

I'm new to Spark and trying to create nested dictionary structure in pyspark...DataFrames.

I have processed a file of CSV values and passed to map function to create a nested dictionary structure. When I'm processing the data inside the map function... The values of nested dictionary is returning as string. I need the nested dictionary to be as dict.

The reason it is converting into `String` is .. by default `MapType` in Spark treats `Map(StringType, StringType, True)`

**Sample Input:**

```
Row(id=207224, id1=11839227, id2=65700, id3=162, TTimeStamp=datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 1, 1, 24, 11), pc=1, DateID_TimeStampUTC=20161201, ModelName=1120007, key=0, key2=5.0, key3=68.0, GbxBrgOilTmpGsAct=69.0, key4=72.0)

def process(row, signals_map, trb_id_u_id):
    signals = {}
    data = {}
    single_payload = {}
    filt_dt = {k: v for k, v in row.asDict().items() if k not in exclude_fields and v is not None}
    log.debug('this is filter data', filt_dt)
    for k, v in filt_dt.items():
        if k not in exclude_filter_fields:
            print('This is key', k)
            k = str(int(signals_map.value.get(k)))
            signals[k] = str(v)
        else:
            k = field_name_map.get(k)
            data[k] = str(v)
    data['signals'] = signals
    data['id'] = trb_id_u_id.value.get(str(data.get('src_trb_id')))
    data['ts_utc'] = derive_tsutc(data.get('ts_utc'))
    single_payload['insrt_ts'] = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    single_payload['data'] = data
    return single_payload


    fnl_data = hist_data.rdd.map(lambda x: process(x,broadcastVar1,broadcastVar2)).toDF()
```

**Current output**

```
{
    "data" : {
        "signals" : "{Key1:Value1,Key2:Value2,Key3:Value3}",
        "id" : "1234",
        "ts_utc" : "1480555451000",
        "pc" : "1"
    },
    "insrt_ts" : "2020-01-03 12:56:13.808887"
}
```

Required Output Format:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "signals" : {
            "Key1":"Value1",
            "Key2":"Value2",
            "Key3":"Value3"
        },
        "id" : "1234",
        "ts_utc" : "1480555451000",
        "pc" : "1"
    },
    "insrt_ts" : "2020-01-03 12:56:13.808887"
}
```

**Atleast neead help in converting this row of dataframe into nested dict in pyspark:**

```
**input dafarame :** 
`Row({"Key1":0,"Key2":5.0,"Key3":68.0,"Key4":69.0,"key5":72.0,"ts_utc":1480555451000,"id":207224,"9.0":9.1000003815})`

**required structure:**

{'data':{'signals':{Key1":1,
                    "Key2":2,
                    "Key3":3,
                    "Key4":4,
                    "key5":5}}
                    "ts_utc":1480555451000,
                    "id":207224

                    }
```

Comment: Add some sample input data and the desired output to get better/faster help.

Comment: @blackbishop .. updated the sample input row. please check and help

Comment: data(the key) in the result itself is a nest dict and it is parsed successfully, but only signals didn't which is wired. what if you move the signals data one level up outside data

Comment: Why not convert your CSV into nested json first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own Spark Schemas in order to read the data in an specific way (without letting Spark infer the types). (For more information, double check the following link: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema). In this case, in order to have the dictionary inside signals, you can define a MapType (which keys and values have StringType)

Below you can find a possible solution to the data input shown.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, MapType

ownSchema = StructType([
    StructField("data", StructType([
      StructField("signals", MapType(StringType(), StringType())),
      StructField("id", StringType()),
      StructField("ts_utc", StringType()),
      StructField("pc", StringType()),
    ])), 
    StructField("insrt_ts", StringType()) 
])
```

And then, you can read the data using something like the following: `spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=ownSchema...)`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for you help. I have used infer schema to the processed RDD and it worked . till now i', trying to use toDF() function, which is truncating the keys which are not type of map. Since dict is referenced as MapType in pyspark. Thank you

Comment: you can not parse `{Key1:Value1,Key2:Value2,Key3:Value3}` with `MapType(StringType(), StringType())` since it is not a valid json. You could do that only if all json properties are enclosed in double quotes i.e `{"Key1":"Value1","Key2":"Value2","Key3":"Value3"}`